# Retrieve values from LIST<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have a problem for retrieving data from a list, I must get the info for every selected record, and I can do that, but I have this data in a list<> and I need it in the textboxes, I have classes for work in my app, this is my Data Layer:

```
public List<Cajas> cajas_upd_cons_caja_detalle(string clienteCodigo, string cajaCodigo, int cajaNumero)
{
    List<Cajas> ListCaj_x_Cod_CajNum = new List<Cajas>();
    string storedProcedure = "CAJAS_UPD_CONS_CAJA_DETALLE"; //stored procedure

    using (DbConnection con = dpf.CreateConnection())
    {
        con.ConnectionString = conStr;
        using (DbCommand cmd = dpf.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = storedProcedure;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            DbParameter param1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param1.DbType = DbType.String;
            param1.ParameterName = "CLIENTE_CODIGO"; //param
            param1.Value = clienteCodigo.Replace(" ", ""); 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

            DbParameter param2 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param2.DbType = DbType.String;
            param2.ParameterName = "CAJA_CODIGO"; //param
            param2.Value = cajaCodigo.Replace(" ", "");
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            DbParameter param3 = cmd.CreateParameter();
            param3.DbType = DbType.String;
            param3.ParameterName = "CAJA_NUMERO"; //param
            param3.Value = cajaNumero;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param3);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (DbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //THIS IS MY CLASS
                        Cajas caja = new Cajas(); //

                        caja.CajaContenido = dr["CONTENIDO"].ToString();
                        caja.CajaEstado = dr["EST"].ToString();
                        caja.FecEmisionDoc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["EMISION"].ToString());
                        caja.FecCaducidDoc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["CADUCIDAD"].ToString());
                        caja.CajaUbi1 = dr["UBI1"].ToString();
                        caja.CajaUbi2 = dr["UBI2"].ToString();
                       ListCaj_x_Cod_CajNum.Add(caja);
                    }
                    catch (System.InvalidCastException)
                    { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ListCaj_x_Cod_CajNum;
}
```

This is my presentation class:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdCadDet_limpiarCampos();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        clienteCodigo = Request.QueryString["cliCod"];
        cajaCodigo = Request.QueryString["cajCod"];
        cajaNumero = Request.QueryString["cajNum"];
        lblUpdCajDet_CliCod.Text = clienteCodigo;
        lblUpdCajDet_CajCod.Text = cajaCodigo;
        lblUpdCajDet_CajNum.Text = cajaNumero;

        //this is only for testing
        List<Cajas> cajastest = cajaUpd_BL.cajas_upd_cons_caja_detalle (clienteCodigo, cajaCodigo, Convert.ToInt32(cajaNumero));

    }
}
```

If y debug the application I can see the values retrieved from the DB, but my question is How can I get them in my presentation class (in the GUI).

I hope someone please can help me.

best regards

Comment: Sidenote: you're executing the query twice, with `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader`. I suggest removing the `ExecuteNonQuery`-call.

Comment: It is up to you. How would you like to display them? The most straight forward idea is using a data grid (table format). Here is a link for you: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/example-of-datagrid-in-asp-net/

Comment: Thanks Caramiriel
I was testing because I had an error and I could not retrieve the data, but that part is solved. I will correct that.

Thanks Feryal,
But this info comes from a other page gridview, It is the detail from every record, because the following will be modify the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks 
I could get the list values:

```
List<Cajas> cajadetalle = cajaUpd_BL.cajas_upd_cons_caja_detalle
            (clienteCodigo, cajaCodigo, Convert.ToInt32(cajaNumero));

        txtUpdCajDet_CajCon.Text = cajadetalle[0].CajaContenido.ToString();
        txtUpdCajDet_CajEst.Text = cajadetalle[0].CajaEstado.ToString();
        txtUpdCajDet_CajFem.Text = cajadetalle[0].FecEmisionDoc.ToString();
        txtUpdCajDet_CajFca.Text = cajadetalle[0].FecCaducidDoc.ToString();
        txtUpdCajDet_CajFal.Text = cajadetalle[0].AltaFecha.ToString();
        txtUpdCajDet_CajFba.Text = cajadetalle[0].BajaFecha.ToString();
        txtUpdCajDet_CajUb1.Text = cajadetalle[0].CajaUbi1.ToString();
        ......
        ......
```

So I can get the values in textboxes